# how does a onChange handler get access to the previous state of variables?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-state

i found following example somewhere and I cannot figure out how it is supposed to work, can someone explain it please, I understand the usage of setState and initializing it, but I don't understand the variable prevInputData! what is calling the setInputData and how the previous state is being passed as parameter when setInputData is being called, i'm so confused!

```
    //state stuff 
    const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({firstName: "", lastName: ""})

    //onChange handler 
    function handleChange(event) {
      const {name, value} = event.target

      setInputData(prevInputData => { //HOW THIS IS SUPPOSED TO WORK?
        return {
            ...prevInputData,
            [name]: value
          }
       });
    }

    //form input 
    <input name="lastName" 
           value={inputData.lastName}
           onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *kind of* misleading. It's not *actually* the state value from the previous render cycle, it's the current state value being passed as an argument to the ***functional state update callback***. By the time the callback is invoked though, during reconciliation, to update state, it is *now* the state from the last render cycle, and returns the next state value.

[Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```
setInputData(prevInputData => { // actually current state when queued
  return {
    ...prevInputData,
    [name]: value
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you, but would you please explain to me how setInputData is being called? the handleChange function is obviously being called with event object as parameter, what exactly is calling setInputData with the current state?

Comment: @nightograph `setInputData` is just a named function returned by the `useState` hook. `handleChange` is invoking it and passing the defined callback function as an argument.

Comment: hey Drew, ok maybe my knowledge of javascript is not there yet, so the browser renders and react registers the function handleChange to be invoked at the change, the change happens and react invokes handleChange with event as function parameter, now in that functino we are invoking setInputData and instead of sending it the new state of the object, we are sending it an anonymous function that take the current status of the data as pareter and return the new, what is invoking that anonymous function? thank you so much

Comment: @nightograph No worries, IMO react has a very steep learning curve if you come from an [imperative](https://codeburst.io/declarative-vs-imperative-programming-a8a7c93d9ad2) background, and confusion can be confounded if you're unfamiliar with passing callbacks around or working with functions as first-class citizens. The react framework is what is invoking the "anonymous" function that was passed.

Comment: oh, i think im getting it - so what you mean is that the setter function setXyz() which useState is returning, can actually be called with an call back instead of a object literal and when you call it with the call back, react invokes that function passing it the current state?

Comment: @nightograph Affirmative.

Answer (score 0):

Input data was set at some point right ? Like say at the first run the values are set to be `firstname:"jhon"` and `lastname:"doe"` now the next time you run setState it already has reference of the previous value because it was set before.

```
 setInputData(prevInputData => { //Get the previous values which were set
        return {
            ...prevInputData, //uses spread operator to add those values here so that they are not lost
            [name]: value //setting new values.
          }
       });
```

In other words if you dont use prevInputData which is just a variable name it can be anything, your previous changes will be overridden. Also by run i mean the current state it holds, not like you could come back after a refresh and it'll be there. its like updating for input boxes, with each input box you leave, the state is updated and retains the previous input box values you added, if you dont do `...prevData` then the previous values you entered will be lost.